# Install android Studio on Solaris/SunOS 11

Tags: android-studio, solaris, sunos

Is it possible to install Android Studio on a Solaris OS.

Trying to compile some open source Java projects using Gradle, the one i am playing around with use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that there is a Solaris compatible version of Android Studio available (not to mention if it's a SPARC vs x86 Solaris), but one option is to install [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Linux, and run it virtually.

Comment: Thanks Tim, stopped wasting time on it. Have setup a Local VM with CentOS and everything works smoothly.